# Is sbt the only option when it comes to scala.js and IntelliJ IDE?

Tags: maven, gradle, intellij-idea, scala.js

I'm writing a scala library that can be compiled into both JVM bytebodes and javascript minified npm package (through scalajs).

It will be released on both maven central and npm public repositories, and be used as a dependency by a company. This makes me reluctant to use sbt and scala IDE, as sbt/ivy doesn't support publishing SNAPSHOT versions, and scala IDE/eclipse has many idiosyncrasies in dependency management.

However, I found most build pipelines for scalajs either use one or the other. E.g.:

- scalajs sbt plugin use sbt but not maven or gradle
- scalor-maven-plugin use scalaIDE but not IntelliJ IDE

If I want to sidestep the finickiness of sbt & scala IDE, while still compile into javascript as npm package, what is my option?